# PHP 2d array - Parents and childs

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to show the parent-child relationship in PHP tree hierarchy using a 2d array?

output(Parent 01 is root parent)( Root parent 0 have the child 01 and child 02, child 01 have the child 005, child 005 have the child 0007.)

```
Parent 01
    Child 01
    Child 02
Parent 02
    Child 04
     Child 005
Parent 03
    child 06
     child 0007
      Child 00008
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to represent a tree structure in a 2D array but a binary tree is doable in a 1D array. See the link below for an example.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-array-implementation/

Alternatively, PHP has no limits (outside of the memory limitations) on the number of dimensions an array can have so why not use a n-dimension array to represent your tree?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use Adjacency lists to store the tree structure. The Adjacency list can be stored in a 2 dimensional array.

The key of the array will be the parent node id. For example 'Parent 01', 'Parent 02', 'Parent 03' etc. The value will be an array containing list of child node ids. For example: 'Child 01', 'Child 02', 'Child 03' etc.